# How to deal with a not-yet-implemented method that will be done by a co-programmer?

Tags: teamwork

This is a question about how to work in teams.

Recently I worked on my first larger (~80 classes, Java) programming project with a team of 6 people, though only 4 of us were continously working on the code. We distributed the work to be done early on and at some point I needed to call a method that was not yet implemented by one of my co-programmers. How is the recommended way to deal with this?

Options I saw, though I don't really like any of them:

1. Writing myself a `//TODO` and revisiting this line of code later to check if the method has been implemented in the meantime.
2. Asking the corresponding team member to implement that *now*.
3. Throwing a custom runtimeException with a clear description of what is not yet implemented. (At least we don't have to search for a long time to find out what is missing)
4. Adding the needed method to *their* class and writing them a `//TODO` in the message body, possibly also send them a quick message about that change. (Now it's not my problem anymore, but this can cause annoying merge conflicts if they were working on this method in the meantime)
5. Defining abstract classes or interfaces for everything before actually writing the code that does the work. (Didn't work too well because these interfaces were often changed)

Comment: I think that workflow where you need a method written by someone else is not right one. You are working on a feature. If that feature requires a method, YOU implement it. If two people are to implement single feature, they either pair, or integrate and communicate so frequently that it almost looks like they pair.

Comment: @Euphoric Multiple times have I come across a situation where a quite big new feature was to be developed within a relatively short timeframe and as such the user interface, business logic and API layers had to be split into different tasks to be worked on simultaneously, otherwise the deadline could never be met. That is exactly where a person working on the UI should only declare data access methods and commands to BL as interfaces and let the other people work on the implementation, while working solely on the UI.

Comment: @DavidPacker What you describe is not the only way to resolve that problem. Vertical slices, frequent integration, small features are all better solutions than Horizontal slices with each person working on separate part.

Comment: @Euphoric I cannot agree more with you. When possible, we go with the way of stripping the complex new feature of non-critical parts (i.e. those which would only improve the UX but are not necessary right away). Sadly, sometimes the options you mentioned, neither the feature stripping, are not possible. Business say, developers do. So while your points are solid, there is also likelihood someone would and will encounter a situation where some kind of feature work-split has to be done in order to fulfil the business' needs.

Comment: @DavidPacker Well. Then it is time to tell The Business, that reality is not so nice, and dumping the crap on the developers is not a way to develop good software.

Comment: @Euphoric One example: I was writing the server/networking stuff and message-parsing and had to call certain methods from the actual serverside logic classes on MessageReceived events. Should I have defined an Interface with these methods instead and provide a method to register an implementation of this eventListener interface?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. But if your code was clearly defined module with clear separation from rest of the code, then you should have written automated tests and not touch code not relevant to your module. And then wait for other side to integrate with you after they are done.

Comment: @Euphoric My code was tested. But it was not completely encapsulated: I called the team member's methods from my code. I just now realized that I could have instead created a way for them to dynamically give my code a reference to their module which my code could then use. For that, I could have defined an interface that they would need to implement. Would that have been a better solution? (I hope it is now clear what I meant)
What does it mean for them "to integrate with me"? That they would edit my code once theirs is ready?

Comment: Meaning "to integrate with you" is that they would implement new code that binds their module and your module together. In ideal scenario, there would be three "modules" two for each of you and your partner. And one that binds the two together. And the third one would be written after both previous are complete.

Comment: @Euphoric That makes sense to me, thanks! The bottom line for most of my scenarios is thus to write better-encapsulated code

Comment: what about _talking_ to him how he wants to handle it?

Comment: "Asking the corresponding team member to implement that now." You're not his boss, you can't order him around. However, you can go ask him when he thinks he will be done with this feature, and if the answer leaves you unable to fulfill your tasks you should talk with your manager so he can reschedule/re-assign the task, another blocking its implementation, or postpone your deadline (discuss it with your colleague first so it doesn't look like masked criticism)

Comment: @Aaron I absolutely agree that I can't order him around. But I can ask him nicely ( which I did a few times and either resulted in him doing it instantly or when he didn't have the time at that moment in me trying out a different option ). I should mention that we didn't have the typical workplace situation as the whole project was 'just' an assignment for university and the team lead didn't have time to manage every detail as he was also doing QA. Anyway, at a real workplace, you're probably right that I/we shouldn't bypass the manager

Comment: @Aganju I did none of these options without the others agreement. The thing is that none of us really had previous experience of coding in teams. This is why I'm asking for a recommended path to take in such situations

Comment: **6.** switch to a programming language where not implemented stuff automatically triggers a compiler warning and, if the function in question is called, clear error message saying where the problem lies?

Comment: @lucidbrot I would say the real "bottom line" to take from Euphoric's comments (particularly the highly upvoted ones) is that with a decent process, you'll largely not have this problem in the first place. There is a reason Euphoric added "[i]n [an] ideal scenario" in the last comment. Often this "nicely decoupled" code/design doesn't happen. It may not even be desirable in some situations as it can be over-engineering and create unnecessary complexity. You certainly don't want good design to be a *requirement* for your team to work efficiently. (You want it to be an outcome.)

Comment: The fact that you're asking the question at all indicates that there's been a failure at some point in the management or design process. You ought not to be in a situation where you're implementing callers before callees in the first place! This sounds like an opportunity to examine problems with your design and scheduling processes.

Comment: @EricLippert Probably true. How would we go about implementing two modules of which one relies on the other under time pressure though, if we don't develop both in parallel? I cannot really imagine all of the team working on the same feature simulateously

Comment: @lucidbrot: I invite you to carefully examine the premises of your question. The purpose of software design methodologies is not to guarantee that parallelism is possible or that everyone your company has hired is productive for eight hours a day. Nor is it to guarantee that the deadlines imposed by your management can be met. The purpose of a design process is to produce a design that meets the needs of the product stakeholders, not to ensure that no one is idle and no one is overworked.

Comment: In short: if it takes an hour to bake a pie, ten bakers will not make a pie in six minutes. If you've got people who can't be productively employed because a dependency is missing, and they cannot implement the dependency, then either put them to work doing something else that is independent of the dependency -- fixing bugs, writing tests, checking documentation for errors, whatever -- or better yet, let them go to the beach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is an interesting question and the answer might be easier than you think.

Simply put, write tests that validate your assumptions. It does not matter if you do the implemenation or your fellow programmers

The long answer.

Any of the options that you list are somewhat passive and require **you** to come back and revisit the code (if any exists) sooner or later.

- *Comments* need to be read and handled by your counterpart responsible for the implementation. Your code cannot be compiled in the meantime. If you check such state in a code repository, your continuous integration pipeline will not work, and it is bad practice anyways ... **never check in broken code**
- *Runtime exceptions* seem better, but are still toxic, because your fellow programmer could assume that the implementation was already done without checking, leaving the system in an unstable state as well. If the method is triggered not so often, it could lead to broken production code ... bad practice as well ... **never check in "not-implemented" exceptions**
- *Waiting for your fellow programmers* for implementation of the methods or a stub is also daunting. It breaks your workflow and the workflow of your fellow programmers. What happens if they are sick, in a meeting a g, on coffee break, do you want to spend your time waiting? ... **don't wait for somebody if you don't have to**
- *implement the missing methods* definitely the best way to go forward. But what happens if your implementation does not satisfy the whole use case and your fellow programmers need to amend or change it? How do you and they make sure that it is still compatible with your intended? The answer is easy again. Write tests that verify, describe and document your intentions. If the tests break, it is easy to notice. If changes in that method need to be done that break your feature ... you see it immediately. You both have a reason to communicate and decide what to do. Split the functionality? Change your implementation, etc... **never check in code that is not sufficiently documented by tests**

To achieve a sufficient level of testing I would suggest you have a look at two disciplines.

1. TDD - test-driven development - this will make sure you describe your intent and sufficiently test it. It also gives you the possibility to mock or fake methods and classes (also by using interfaces) that are not implemented yet. The code and tests will still compile and allow you to test your own code in isolation of your fellow programmers' code. (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development )
2. ATDD - acceptance test-driven development - this will create an outer loop (around the TDD loop) which helps you to test the feature as a whole. These tests will only turn green when the whole feature is implemented, thus giving you an automatic indicator when your fellows complete their work. Quite neat if you ask me.

Caveat: In your case, I would only write simple acceptance tests and not try to bring in too much of the business side, as it would just be too much to start with. Write simple integration tests that put together all the parts of the system the feature requires. That's all that is required

This will allow you to put your code in a Continous Integration pipeline and produce a highly reliable implementation.

If you want to get further in that topic check the following links:

- https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDrivenDevelopment.html
- https://www.amazon.de/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882
- https://www.amazon.de/Refactoring-Improving-Design-Existing-Technology/dp/0201485672/ref=sr_1_1?s=books-intl-de&ie=UTF8&qid=1514648927&sr=1-1&keywords=refactoring

Answer (score 103):

**Ask for stubs.**

Or write them yourself. Either way, you and your coworkers need to agree on the interfaces and how they're intended to be used. That agreement needs to be relatively solidified so you *can* develop against stubs -- not to mention, so you can create your own mocks for your unit testing...

Comment: ^^ This.  If you're properly using interfaces, you shouldn't need the implementations until the other guy is done writing them.

Comment: And to further Robert's comment, if you're not properly using interfaces in a project specifically designed to be split among multiple people, well you're gonna have a bad time...

Comment: It's a shame that Java doesn't have header files. In the C/C++ world you can work out your APIs and write all your headers first, a lack of implementation then becomes a problem for the linker. (Slight simplification, the ABI needs to remain constant as well for it to just be a linker matter).

Comment: @WesToleman Amusingly, one of my favorite things about Java is that it doesn't have header files.  The "interfaces" that Robert and corsiKa mentioned fill that role perfectly.  You work out your APIs first, write the interfaces, and a lack of concrete implementation isn't a problem for the compiler.

Comment: @GrandOpener And when the class is there, most IDE's will whine (also compiler), and IDE's can create a stub method, usually throwing an exception, but at least your software compiles. If your workflow consists mostly of getting compile ready code with unit tests you can easily ensure your project "Should work"

Comment: @WesToleman Does that work out well for you? In my ears that sounds a hell of a lot like water-fall style, and my guess is that you have to update the interface further when you realize that you've misse this "important parameter"?

Comment: While I'm certainly not downvoting this answer, I semi-disagree with it. The real answer is to minimize the chance of this situation occurring in the first place, but this is a process answer, in the vein of Euphoric's comments, not a design or technical answer. A process answer is likely not too useful to the OP or a junior developer who is not in a position to change the process. While stubs are a relatively straightforward solution (another is to just implement the method you need if it is fairly independent), I have rarely needed to use stubs in this capacity.

Comment: @netigger I'm just a hobbyist mainly working alone so I don't have enough data to really say at this point.

Comment: @DerekElkins what are stubs, if not a cheap implementation

Comment: @emory They are incorrect implementations.

Answer (score 6):

In your situation, I would talk to the team member with responsibility for that function. It may be that they are in a position to prioritise the development of that function so you are able to start using it sooner.

I would steer clear of your fourth option. You've written all your code, and as you say, you no longer consider it to be your problem. Your colleague then writes the implementation of the function, and no longer considers it to be their problem. Who's actually going to test that the code YOU wrote works correctly?

Comment: You should ask for the _API_ for that function which should result in one or more interfaces.   It might be a good idea to do this together, as you will need to use this interface so you can design the initial test cases based on your input.  The actual implementation can then come later (including possible API changes)